# Conditionally showing a button with DJANGO template language

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, dom, django-templates

I have a page that should show a button if the user is marked as "facturable" (billable), otherwise, the button should not appear. I tried  the following code:

```
{% if form_experfil.facturable %}
     <a href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' %}?pagref=factdatshow" type="button"
                       class="btn btn-primary waves-effect"> Consultar datos de facturación</a>                      
{% endif %}
```

But it keeps showing. This and other fails make me think that the {% if %} tag behaviour isnh't as straightforward as I thought, and it does not just clip the html code down to the endif tag, but something gets rendered first. Is there somewhere where this is formally documented without mystical references?. Is there a way to just show this button when the customer has this data and not show it otherwise?.

This is the view:

```
def perfil_view(request):
perfil = ExUserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
facturar = perfil.facturable
if facturar:
    factdat = Factdat.objects.get(cliente=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_perfil = perfilEditForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    form_experfil = experfilEditForm(data=request.POST, instance=perfil)
    if facturar:
        form_factdat = factdatEditForm(data=request.Post, instance=perfil)
    if all([form_perfil.is_valid(), form_experfil.is_valid(), form_factdat.is_valid()]):
        form_perfil.save()
        form_experfil.save()
        form_factdat.save(commit=facturar)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('incid/perfil')
else:
    form_perfil = perfilEditForm(instance=request.user)
    form_experfil = experfilEditForm(instance=perfil)
    if facturar:
        form_factdat = factdatEditForm(instance=factdat)
template = "incid/perfil.html"
if facturar:
    return render(request, template, {
        'form_perfil': form_perfil,
        'form_experfil': form_experfil,
        'form_factdat': form_factdat
    })
else:
    return render(request, template, {
        'form_perfil': form_perfil,
        'form_experfil': form_experfil
    })
```

and these are the models:

```
eclass ExUserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                            primary_key=True,
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
logo = ResizedImageField(size=[200, 200],
                         crop=['middle', 'center'],
                         quality=75, upload_to='static/logos/',
                         default='logos/no-img.jpg')
facturable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)


class Factdat(models.Model):
    cliente = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                   verbose_name='cliente_fact',
                                   primary_key=True,
                                   default='',
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    nomfact = models.CharField(max_length=240,
                               verbose_name='nomfact')
    niffact = models.CharField(max_length=16,
                               verbose_name='niffact')
    mailfact = models.EmailField(max_length=254,
                                 verbose_name='mailfact')
    telfact = models.CharField(max_length=24,
                               verbose_name='telfact')
    persfact = models.CharField(max_length=128,
                                verbose_name='persfact')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Fact_dat"
        verbose_name_plural = "Fact_datos"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cliente)
```

and just in case, here is the full page:

```
def perfil_view(request):
perfil = ExUserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
facturar = perfil.facturable
if facturar:
    factdat = Factdat.objects.get(cliente=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_perfil = perfilEditForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    form_experfil = experfilEditForm(data=request.POST, instance=perfil)
    if facturar:
        form_factdat = factdatEditForm(data=request.Post, instance=perfil)
    if all([form_perfil.is_valid(), form_experfil.is_valid(), form_factdat.is_valid()]):
        form_perfil.save()
        form_experfil.save()
        form_factdat.save(commit=facturar)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('incid/perfil')
else:
    form_perfil = perfilEditForm(instance=request.user)
    form_experfil = experfilEditForm(instance=perfil)
    if facturar:
        form_factdat = factdatEditForm(instance=factdat)
template = "incid/perfil.html"
if facturar:
    return render(request, template, {
        'form_perfil': form_perfil,
        'form_experfil': form_experfil,
        'form_factdat': form_factdat
    })
else:
    return render(request, template, {
        'form_perfil': form_perfil,
        'form_experfil': form_experfil
    })
```

Comment: The `if` statement looks fine. Can we see your models and views

Comment: There they are.